# DotSpatial Plugins for Measure, attributes, and query

Tags: c#, dotspatial

I want the end product user to open the attributes, measure task and query the shapefile data using the DotSpatial library in C#.

I have dll with me but when I create the folder in solution and add the dll it doesn't show any change in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to include DotSpatial.Plugins.Measure, and DotSpatial.Plugins.AttributeDataExplorer, both of which can be found in the Extension Manager. (See [Finding and Installing the WebMap Extension](http://mudnug.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/finding-and-installing-the-webmap-extension/) for help with plugins.)

The former adds a measure tool, and the latter lets you [view and filter attributes](http://mudnug.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/getting-started-with-attribute-data-explorer/).